# Filtering data from XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am using this filter function for my search bar. But it doesn't seems to be working.

The error that I am having is

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method refresh through a reference with static type spark.components:List.   Malls.mxml  /SGshopping/src/views   line 15 Flex Problem

and

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1119: Access of possibly undefined property filterFunction through a reference with static type spark.components:List.  Malls.mxml  /SGshopping/src/views   line 14 Flex Problem

Sorry guys. I am still learning. This is really confusing and where did i do it wrongly?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 

        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Malls"
        creationComplete="malls.send()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:HTTPService id="malls" url="assets/employees.xml" 
                       result="data=malls.lastResult.list.employee"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function filterDemo():void{
                list.filterFunction=searchDemo;    - I am having errors here
                list.refresh();                     - and here
            }

            private function searchDemo(item:Object):Boolean{
                var isMatch:Boolean=false;
                if(item.name.toLowerCase().search(search.text.toLowerCase())!=-1){
                    isMatch=true;
                }
                return isMatch;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:navigationContent/>
    <s:titleContent>
        <s:TextInput id="search" change="filterDemo()" x="10" y="10" prompt="Search"/>
    </s:titleContent>


    <s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
            dataProvider="{data}"
            change="navigator.pushView(MallsDetails, list.selectedItem)">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer
                    label="{data.firstName} {data.lastName}"
                    messageField="title"/>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>


</s:View>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data filtering for XML. Flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817375/data-filtering-for-xml-flex)

Answer (score 0):

Error Type 1061 and Type 1119 Above two error clear shows No filterFunction property and refresh method available in List Control it belongs to `ListCollectionView` Class So your case try to convert employee.xml to XMLListCollection.

Where data variable declared? Normally inside itemRenderer we can access data get and setter outside itemRenderer simply we can't access.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 

        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Malls"
        creationComplete="malls.send()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:HTTPService id="malls" url="assets/employees.xml" 
                       result="malls_resultHandler(event)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [Bindable]
            private var employeeList:XMLListCollection; //instead data

            private function malls_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                employeeList = new XMLListCollection(new XMLList(malls.lastResult.mallD));
            }

            private function filterDemo():void{
                employeeList.filterFunction=searchDemo;    //Here employeeList instead of list control 
                employeeList.refresh();                    //List control doesn't have filterFunction and refresh function.
            }

            private function searchDemo(item:Object):Boolean{
                var isMatch:Boolean=false;
                if(item.name.toLowerCase().search(search.text.toLowerCase())!=-1){
                    isMatch=true;
                }
                return isMatch;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:navigationContent/>
    <s:titleContent>
        <s:TextInput id="search" change="filterDemo()" x="10" y="10" prompt="Search"/>
    </s:titleContent>


    <s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
            dataProvider="{employeeList}"
            change="navigator.pushView(MallsDetails, list.selectedItem)">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer
                    label="{data.firstName} {data.lastName}"
                    messageField="title"/>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>


</s:View>
```

Based on your XML Struture:

```
var response:XML = malls.lastResult as XML;

var mallIDXMLList:XMLList = response.mallD;           

employeeList = new XMLListCollection(mallIDXMLList);
```

Comment: Thank you. But now there are no data in the list.

Comment: Show your XML struture

Comment: <list>
    <mallD>
     <id>1</id>
     <name>Ion Orchard</name>
     <address>2 Orchard Turn</address>
     <time>10am - 10pm</time>
     <pcode>Singapore 238801</pcode>
     <officePhone>+65 6238 8228</officePhone>
     <email>customercare@ionorchard.com.sg</email>
     <picture>Ion.png</picture>
    </mallD>